Show $M$ is a compact surface diffeomorphic to $\Bbb T^2$
Consider the lattice $$H:=\{(e^m,e^n)\mid m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$$
which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2$ via $(e^m,e^n)\leftrightarrow (m,n).$
Consider the quotient space $ M=\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}/H $. I want to show that $M$ is a compact surface diffeomorphic to $\Bbb T^2$. Here $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}:=\big\lbrace (x,y):x,y>0\big\rbrace$. Here I am taking the quotient in the same standard sense as is usually done with $\Bbb T^2=\Bbb R^2/ \Bbb Z^2$.

How can this be shown?

I am familiar with the standard exercise in topology which gives $\Bbb T^2=\Bbb R^2/ \Bbb Z^2$. Now for my consideration I would expect that $M\simeq \Bbb T^2$ because a quotient of $\Bbb R^2$ over $\Bbb Z^2$ should intuitively be diffeomorphic to a quotient of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ over $H$. There should be a well behaved map (isomorphism at least) $\Bbb T^2 \to M$.

This is pretty much obvious because you’re mapping everything over by the exponential, so apart from some exponential-relabelling, it’s the same quotient. More precisely and generally, we have the following theorem:

Theorem.
For $i\in \{1,2\}$, let $G_i$ be a Lie group acting smoothly from the right on a smooth manifold $X_i$, and suppose the orbit manifold $X_i/G_i$ exists. Let $\pi_i:X_i\to X_i/G_i$ denote the canonical projections (which are smooth surjective submersions). Suppose also that we have a Lie-group isomorphism $\rho:G_1\to G_2$ and a diffeomorphism $f:X_1\to X_2$ which is $\rho$-equivariant, i.e for all $x_1\in X_1$ and $g_1\in G_1$,
\begin{align}
f(x_1\cdot g_1)=f(x_1)\cdot \rho(g_1).
\end{align}
Then, $f$ uniquely descends to a diffeomorphism $\widetilde{f}:X_1/G_1\to X_2/G_2$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_1 @>{f}>> X_2\\
@V{\pi_1}VV @VV{\pi_2}V \\
X_1/G_1 @>> {\widetilde{f}}> X_2/G_2
\end{CD}$$

To prove this theorem, note that $\pi_2\circ f$ is a smooth map which is constant on the fibers of $\pi_1$: for all $x_1\in X_1$ and $g_1\in G_1$, we have
\begin{align}
(\pi_2\circ f)(x_1\cdot g_1)&=\pi_2(f(x_1\cdot g_1))=\pi_2(f(x_1)\cdot \rho(g_1))=\pi_2(f(x_1))=(\pi_2\circ f)(x_1),
\end{align}
where in the second equality, we have used that $f$ is $\rho$-equivariant. Now, since $\pi_1$ is a surjective submersion, it follows (by the universal property of surjective submersions) that $f$ descends uniquely to a smooth map $\widetilde{f}$ which makes the above diagram commute. Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism and $\rho$ is an isomorphism, we can repeat the argument with $f^{-1}:X_2\to X_1$ which will now be $\rho^{-1}$-equivariant, and a little diagram chasing shows that the unique map obtained by making $\pi_1\circ f^{-1}$ descend through $\pi_2$ is actually the inverse map of $\widetilde{f}$. Hence, $\widetilde{f}:X_1/G_1\to X_2/G_2$ is a diffeomorphism.
Another way of expressing this proof would be to say that $\pi_2\circ f:X_1\to X_2/G_2$ is a smooth surjective submersion (since it’s the composition of a diffeomorphism with a surjective submersion) which makes the same identifications as $\pi_1$, i.e the equivalence relations induced by these surjective maps are the same. More explicitly, we mean that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}_{\pi_2\circ f}:=\{(x,y)\in X_1\times X_1\,:\, (\pi_2\circ f)(x)=(\pi_2\circ f)(y)\}
\end{align}
is equal to
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}_{\pi_1}:=\{(x,y)\in X_1\times X_1\,:\, \pi_1(x)=\pi_1(y)\}.
\end{align}
Thus, by ’uniqueness’ of quotient manifolds (which I essentially re-proved in my previous paragrah), we have $X_1/G_1\cong X_2/G_2$ via a unique diffeomorphism (namely $\widetilde{f}$) making the above diagram commute.

Corollary.
For $i\in \{1,2\}$, let $G_i$ be a Lie group and $H_i$ a closed subgroup (so it is an embedded Lie subgroup), and let $H_i$ act on $G_i$ from the right by translations. Suppose we have a Lie group isomorphism $f:G_1\to G_2$ which restricts to an isomorphism $H_1\to H_2$. Then, there is a unique diffeomorphism $\widetilde{f}:G_1/H_1\to G_2/H_2$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G_1 @>{f}>> G_2\\
@V{\pi_1}VV @VV{\pi_2}V \\
G_1/H_1 @>> {\widetilde{f}}> G_2/H_2
\end{CD}$$

Here, we simply apply the above theorem with $G_i$ playing the role of $X_i$ above, and $H_i$ playing the role of the group $G_i$ above, and let $\rho=f|_{H_1\to H_2}$, and keep in mind that quotients of Lie groups by closed subgroups always exist (as smooth manifolds such that the canonical projection is a smooth surjective submersion).

So, with all of this in mind, you can apply the corollary to the map $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2_{>0}$, $f(x,y):=(e^x,e^y)$, to deduce the diffeomorphisms
\begin{align}
\Bbb{T}^2\cong\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2\cong \Bbb{R}^2_{>0}/H,
\end{align}
where the second one is the natural diffeomorphism induced by $f$.
